# Fixing or replacing Python IDLE on Mac OS

Tags: python, python-idle

I recently ran a .py file to IDLE that caused IDLE to crash (after running for some time). While it was running I tried many things including Force Quit etc.  After the crash I tried opening IDLE and got the message that the port was missing? (something to that effect).  After a day I tried IDLE and the the offending py file automatically restarted on IDLE.  I closed IDLE and deleted the offending py file and IDLE (1.24, Python 2.54) finally appeared in it's regular form.  I created a new simple py file and IDLE ran it correctly but I could not run another py file.  I also noticed that the new py file also created a .pyc copy.

Hopefully this isn;t too confusing.  Do I need to reinstall IDLE?  Is there a simpler fix?

Comment: Not using IDLE in the first place is a good way to fix the problem. It's nearly universally reviled.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  If I go to a text editor do you suggest I just go direct to the terminal window or is there another editor that you suggest?